# How to refresh cached on AMP site with path? like https://example.com/path

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

This [link](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache) explain in detail how to refresh the cache for an AMP page.

For this to work on must have a public key on site with this exact location on site `https://example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub`

The address of our site is like `https://example.com/path/`, the `example.com` domain points to another site and the `/path` is deployed separately. So in this scenario how can I update/refresh cache as I cannot host the `public key` at the location required by Google.

Comment: Try the [guidelines posted by github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cache-guidelines.md). It provides a guide to the 3rd party for cache implementation. Also you can check here whenever you have [issues](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/troubleshooting/amp-cache-debugging) related to cache.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 checked these and other available info but could not find any. Will post this as issue on amphtml github as issue